# Smarty - change cache directory

Tags: php, caching, smarty3

I'm using Smarty for a website, but I'm annoyed I have to declare the templates dir, the cache dir and the compile dir every time I initiate Smarty, like so :

```
$smarty = new Smarty();
$smarty->setCacheDir(__DIR__ . '/cache/smarty/');
$smarty->setCompileDir(__DIR__ . '/cache/smarty_c/');
$smarty->setTemplateDir(__DIR__ . '/templates/');
```

Is there a way (By defining variables in my configuration file which is loaded on every page, for instance), to tell Smarty once and for all which are these directories, so I don't have to tell it every time?

Comment: Do all sites have access to the same smarty instance? Or are you doing `new Smarty()` every time?

Comment: I initiate Smarty every time (I don't keep it as a global variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I somewhat solved the issue by creating a new class which extended the Smarty class, but I'm still open to new kind of answers.

```
class MySmarty extends Smarty
{
    const SMARTY_TEMPLATES = __DIR__ . '/../templates/';
    const SMARTY_COMPILED  = __DIR__ . '/../cache/smarty_c/';
    const SMARTY_CACHE     = __DIR__ . '/../cache/smarty/';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplateDir(self::SMARTY_TEMPLATES);
        $this->setCompileDir(self::SMARTY_COMPILED);
        $this->setCacheDir(self::SMARTY_CACHE);
        parent::__construct();
    }
}
```